# SMS New Line from Azure Logic Apps

Tags: azure, twilio, azure-logic-apps

I am sending an SMS using Twilio using the 'Send Text Message' app block within Azure logic apps. I am struggling to insert any line returns in the messages that are sent.

I have tried the following in the 'Text' fields of the block:

First Line \r Second Line

First Line \n Second Line

First Line "\r" Second Line

First Line "\n" Second Line

First Line %0A Second Line

First Line "%0A" Second Line

I have also tried adding the above strings using the expression builder.

Am I missing something?

Text Box Snip:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The answer is to simply format the text field as you want the message to appear, i.e put each new line on a new line in the box.

[image]